# Keras predict_generator output differs every time

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-2, resnet

in the last 2 months I was stucked with this issue and it drove me crazy until I realized my "probabilities" vector from predict_generator is simply wrong.

I'm using keras 2, and I've a **test** folder with sub-directories that contain images (not necessarily same amount of images)

then I import my model, load the weights and do this:

```
from keras.applications import ResNet50
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights=None, input_shape=(3,224,224),classes=N)
model.load_weights(model_path)
probs1 = model.predict_generator(batches, steps=batches.n/64, verbose=1)
probs2 = model.predict_generator(batches, steps=batches.n/64, verbose=1)
```

and I don't why but probs1 != probs2 when probs2 seems like the "correct" predictions.

P.S.
batches.n/64 is not an integer

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3296). But it should be fixed already. 
Try to put `datagen.reset()` before `model.predict_generator()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
steps=batches.n/64
```

to

```
steps=batches.n//64
```

this convert steps to an integer.